# Transfer NSData to the Apple Watch using Watch Connectivty

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, watchos-2

I am trying to send an image that I am fetching using Facebook's Graph API, then take the url data and sent it to the watch where it can be displayed.

Here is how I am fetching and attempting to send the data.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
            session = WCSession.defaultSession()
            session.delegate = self
            session.activateSession()
        }

        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/picture?type=large&redirect=false", parameters:nil).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                print(result)

                let dict = result["data"] as! NSDictionary
                if let urlString = dict.valueForKey("url") as? String {
                    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
                    let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
                    self.session.transferUserInfo(["imageData":imageData!])
                }

            }
        })
    }
```

and here is how I am handling the transfer on the watch's end.

```
override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()

        //initialize session
        if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
            session = WCSession.defaultSession()
            session.delegate = self
            session.activateSession()
        }
    }

    func session(session: WCSession, didFinishUserInfoTransfer userInfoTransfer: WCSessionUserInfoTransfer, error: NSError?) {
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error?.description)
        }
        else {
            print("User info transfer success")
        }
    }

    func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {
        print(userInfo["imageData"])
    }
```

Nothing seems to be working, no userInfo is being printed out along with associated data that should be being sent. My end goal would be to fetch multiple images all at once using the facebook API then send all that data over in an array, is this possible? Is there a limit to how many images I could transfer to the watch at once? Ideally I would like to send 10+ images on a background thread.

Comment: Move the `didFinishUserInfoTransfer` method to the sending side, and see if it returns an error after you call `transferUserInfo`

Comment: however, keep in mind that the maximum limit in the use of this data transfer system (userInfoTransfer) is 225KB (if I remember correctly), after which the system returns an error Payload limit exceeded